# RuntimeWarning: divide by zero in log and invalid value in multiply

Tags: python, numpy, conv-neural-network

I have the following code

```
# weighted input:
Z = np.array(...) 

# activation for hidden layer:                
A = np.where(Z > 0, Z, Z * 0.01) 

# activation for last layer:
A = 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-Z)) 

# cost function for the output at last layer:    
cost =  np.sum(np.nan_to_num(-Y*np.log(A)-(1-Y)*np.log(1-A)))

# derivative of cost function:
dA = (A - Y) / A * (1 - A)  

# derivative of hidden layer:
dZ = np.ones_like(cache)
dZ[cache < 0] = 0.01

# derivative of last layer:
dZ = np.exp(-Z)/(1 + np.exp(-Z))**2
```

When I train the neural network, with a certain **learning rate** (0.1 or 0.5, but NOT when learning rate = 0.01) I got the following warning at some iteration:

```
D:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:21: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
D:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:21: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
```

My questions are:

1. Which line of code caused the warning? I guess the line for `cost` as it has `log()`, but why did the warning mention about `divide`? The only `divide` operation I had was the derivative of last layer, but that line didn't have `log()`.
2. Which part did the warning about `invalid value in multiply` came from: `Y*np.log(A)` or `(1-Y)*np.log(1-A)`?
3. Does the warning made my networks' result invalid?
4. How to resolve the warning issue?

Could you please help? Thanks in advance.

I tried kmario23's suggestion using `expit(Z)` but still got the following:

```
Cost after iteration 0: 0.954719
Cost after iteration 100: 0.321576
Cost after iteration 200: 0.291157
D:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:21: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
D:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:21: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
Cost after iteration 300: inf
Cost after iteration 400: inf
Cost after iteration 500: inf
Cost after iteration 600: inf
Cost after iteration 700: inf
Cost after iteration 800: inf
```

**New info**:
I added some lines in the original code to ensure AL is never to be 0 or 1:

```
min_nonzero = np.min(AL[np.nonzero(AL)])
AL[AL == 0] = min_nonzero
AL[AL == 1] = 0.999
cost =  np.sum(np.nan_to_num(-Y*np.log(AL)-(1-Y)*np.log(1-AL)))
```

then I got the following error

```
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in _wrapreduction(obj, ufunc, method, axis, dtype, out, **kwargs)
     84                 return reduction(axis=axis, out=out, **passkwargs)
     85 
---> 86     return ufunc.reduce(obj, axis, dtype, out, **passkwargs)
     87 
     88 

ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity
```

Would that help to find out the underlying reason of the original problem of `divide by zero in log`?

**Update**
I reversed anything back to the original code, but changed the learning rate from 0.01 to 0.009 and the network was trained without runtime warnings. I simply couldn't understand what the underlying issue was.

Comment: "Which line of code caused the warning?" Check your call stack. We are not mediums...

Comment: Or at the very least provide a [mcve]...

Comment: That I can't tell because the training function is a series of function calls that includes forward pass, backward pass, calculating error and updating weight matrix for each layer. The only error message came out is the one I provided in my question. I would love to provide a MCV example but unsure how to do that. Should I copy all the code in a notepad and upload it here?

Comment: `np.where(Z > 0, Z, Z * 0.01)` scales negative values, but does nothing to 0s.  Is that intentional?

Comment: @hpaulj yes, that's called a `Leaky-ReLU` activation function in Deep Learning! c.f. [`Leaky-ReLU`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)#Leaky_ReLUs)

Comment: I'm not sure why my question is considered as unclear or not useful. There are lots of questions asking similar issue of divide encounter by log. Those questions were more concerned about the log(0) but none asked about the `divide` aspect in the warning message.

Comment: @Jason Mathematically, the gradient for ReLU or Leaky-ReLU is undefined at zero. Practically, we can either include zero in the left half-space or right half-space (It doesn't make much difference either way). So, there's no issue with gradient computation.

Comment: Thanks, kmario23. What do you mean by it doesn't make much difference, is it because the derivative of Leaky-ReLU isn't involved in the log()

Comment: @Jason What I meant was that it doesn't make much difference to the accuracy that your model achieves if you include zero in the left or right half-space.

Comment: I asked because `np.log(0)` produces the log warning.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, the culprit is the way how `A` is computed, in a numerically unstable way, and the issue might arise in following line:

```
A = 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-Z))
```

So, I'd suggest you to replace the above line with [**SciPy's expit funciton**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.special.expit.html) which is much more stable.

```
from scipy.special import expit 
A = expit(Z)
```

And also much faster than manually implementing it using NumPy.

The range of values that `expit` produces range from `[0, 1]` - closed interval.

For example: Very high +ve values would be approximated as 1 and vey high -ve values would be approximated as 0.

```
expit([-np.inf, -1.5,  0,   1.5,   np.inf])
array([ 0.   ,  0.182, 0.5, 0.817, 1.])
```

Comment: Hi kmario23, thanks for your suggestion. I tried but still get the following error (please see my edited question above). Could you also please advise whether `expit(z)` would ever return 0 or 1?

Comment: @Jason Could you please tell what's your `line-21`? that's where we have to start debugging..

Comment: @ kmario23, thank you for providing example of expit that returns 0 or 1. Could you please clarify what `line-21` you referred to? Could you please have a look at the **new info** I added in the question above?